# Wordpress Still Requesting Old Url

Tags: urls

I have a WordPress site that is working locally. In order to test the mobile design, I changed the URL from settings to my local IP. It worked fine, and then I changed it back to localhost. But the problem is accrued today, my local IP is changed and now WordPress still redirecting me to my old URL.

My local IP is 192.168.1.40 now

I changed the site URL from the database manually and still have the problem.

[image]

Comment: Is the site URL correct in WordPress? Here's the documentation for that: [Changing the Site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#changing-the-site-url)

Answer (score 0):

sound like this might be your dns issue, try to change dns to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4(google DNS) in network preferences.